# capture the output of slurm account command to python dictionary

Tags: python, scripting, slurm

I am trying to capture the output of the following slurm (https://hpc.nmsu.edu/onboarding/supercomputing/slurm/job-statistics/) command :

`sacct -a -j <job_id> --format=user%10,jobname%10,node%10,start%10,end%10,elapsed%10,MaxRSS`
that output this:

```
                   User                  JobName                 NodeList                    Start                      End                  Elapsed     MaxRSS
```

---

```
     user_name                    job10000000                machine00      2022-01-25T12:35:11      2022-01-25T12:36:02                 00:00:51            
                                    something                machine00      2022-01-25T12:35:11      2022-01-25T12:36:02                 00:00:51          0 
                                  job10000000                machine00      2022-01-25T12:35:12      2022-01-25T12:36:02                 00:00:50     24000K
```

into a dictionary using python, my code is as following:

```
slurm_cmd = 'sacct -a -j '+ str(job_id) + ' --format=user%10,jobname%10,node%10,start%10,end%10,elapsed%10,MaxRSS'
p = subprocess.Popen(slurm_cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = p.stdout.read().decode()
header, *data = output.splitlines()   
for datarow in data: 
    if data.index(datarow) == 1:
        dict_ = dict(zip(header.split(), datarow.split()))
```

my expectation is something like this:

```
dict_ = {
    "User" : 'user_name',
    "NodList": 'machine00',
    "Start" : '2022-01-25T12:35:12',
    "End"  : '2022-01-25T12:36:02',
    "Elapsed": '00:00:51',
    "MaxRSS"  : '24000K'
    }
```

Does anyone did this or something similar before?

Comment: do not use `dict` as variable name as it is a keyword

Answer (score 0):

```
header = output.splitlines()[0]
datarow = output.splitlines()[2]
dict_output = {k: v for k, v in zip(header.split(), datarow.split())}
```

Comment: can you put here the output of this code ?

Comment: it looks like your expectation but I am not sure what your environment is

Comment: want to capture that "MaxRSS" value (24000K) to the dictionary even if not occurs in the first row

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: the objective is to parse that slurm outputted table, each column header should be a key, and each key should be associated with a value that  is the first occurrence of an non empty field in all rows of each column   in our case  ` dict_ = {
    "User" : 'user_name',
    "NodList": 'machine00',
    "Start" : '2022-01-25T12:35:12',
    "End"  : '2022-01-25T12:36:02',
    "Elapsed": '00:00:51',
    "MaxRSS"  : '24000K'
    }`